# Javascriptの掛け算の結果が計算機の結果と異なるのはなぜですか？

Tags: javascript

本当にちいさな質問なのですがJavascriptで

```js
alert(19.4*50);
```

とすると「969.9999999999999」とでてきます。
けど、計算機で計算すると「970」と表示されます。。。
なぜ計算結果が異なるのか不明なのですがご存じの方いらっしゃればご教授おねがいします・・・。

すみません。私のブラウザー環境ですが
IE：10
Chrome： 69.0.3497.100
です

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascriptに限らず、計算機で小数を表現する際に用いられる浮動小数点は精度が有限であり、正しい値を表現することができないということが原因です。

詳しい解説はこちらの質問に多くの回答があるので参考になるかと存じます。

[c# - 計算式『10/3*3』について - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27407/%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E5%BC%8F-10-33-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

Comment: う・・・。すみません参考質問読みましたが今一わかりませんでした。ひとまずJavaScriptにかかわらずPCで小数点あり数値は正しく取り扱うことは不可能ということでしょうか？それではJavaScriptで対応を取るとすれば[対処法](http://blog.asial.co.jp/1191)のようなことをする必要がある。ということでしょうか？？※浮動小数点あたりは目を背けていたので知識激乏しいです・・・

Comment: decimal.jsというJavascriptで小数をより正確に扱うためのライブラリがあるので、これを利用してみるのはいかがでしょうか。 https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js （Javascriptで小数を扱う方法として、別質問に分けた方が良い気もしますが……）

Comment: decimal.js！実は色々と調べていましてmath.jsとどう違うのだろうかと悩んでいました。質問をひとまずもう一つつくります！

Answer (score 10):

基本的には PicoSushi さんの言われている事柄は間違っていないんですが、リンク先は主に10進数での有限精度の計算について書かれてあるものなので補足です。

JavaScriptでは、数値を64ビットの2進浮動小数点数で表しています。2進数では、10進表記で`19.4`となるような(人間から見たら)単純な値でも、計算機内で正確に表すことができず、無限に続く循環小数になってしまいます。

```
19.4 = (2進表記)10011.01100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001...
```

これを64ビットに詰め込むため、64ビットの2進浮動小数点数では内部的にこんなことになっています。

```
0100000000110011011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
-^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(`_`を付したところは符号(`0`がプラス)、`^^^`を付したところが指数部(小数点位置を表している)です。)

見比べてもらうと分かりますが、`0110`が無限に続くはずが途中で打ち切られています。無限に続く部分を有限に収める時に、単に切り捨てとせず四捨五入(2進法なんで零捨一入ですが)が起こるため`0`で終わるはずのところが`1`になっていることもあります。

とにかく、切り捨てにしろ切り上げにしろ無限に続く値を有限ビット数で表せば誤差が入ってきます。計算の中身によっては、2進数を10進表記に変換する場合にも四捨五入が入るので、たまたま小数点を含む計算でも10進数で計算した時と同じ結果が表示される時がありますが、本当にたまたまでしかありません。

元々誤差を含んでいる値を元に計算しているのですから、計算結果も誤差を含んでいます。上記の「たまたま」がうまく働かないとご質問にあるような結果が表示されることになります。

---

と言うわけで

#### 数値として2進浮動小数点数が用いられる場合

- 定数を10進表記で表していても内部では2進数で処理される
- 有限の2進数で小数を表した場合の計算は、常に誤差を伴いうる

と言うことを覚えていただいた方が良いでしょう。

普通の計算機は「計算に10進法を使う」または「うまく四捨五入している」のどちらかの理由で、「970」と言う値が表示されているものと思われます。

ただ、「10進数型」と言うものが手軽に使える場合でも、答えが無限小数になるような場合には誤差が含まれることは PicoSushi さんの回答内にあるリンクの通りです。

計算機と同じような結果を得たかったら、あなたのコードでも「計算に10進法を使う」か「うまく四捨五入している」必要があります。

Comment: 「元々誤差を含んでいる値を元に計算しているのですから、～」←これでとても納得いきました！わかりやすく解説していただき本当にありがとうございます！