# JavaScriptでの小数点の扱いについて

Tags: javascript

すみません。[前回質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49377/javascript%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E7%AE%97%E3%81%AE%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%8C%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E6%A9%9F%E3%81%AE%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%A8%E7%95%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)の続きになります。

JavaScriptで小数点を扱う四則演算をしようとすると、どうすればよいでしょうか？
前回コメントにて[decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js)をおしえていただきましたが、[math.js](http://mathjs.org/)とはどう違うのでしょうか？

ご教授おねがいします。

Comment: どんなやり方をしても本質的に誤差は避けられないので、「どうすればよいでしょうか？」については目的次第です。例えば銀行の利息計算などでは10進法に基づいて四捨五入の仕方まできちんと決めてありますし、電卓(計算機アプリ)は10進計算(をしているものが多い)、Excelなんかだと「うまく四捨五入している」になります。どんな目的の「四則計算」でしょう?

Comment: 今回発生してしまったのは、単価と数量から金額を求めるというものです。割り算に関しては端数の丸め対応を決めていましたが、その他の計算にかんしては丸め対応は考えられていません…。最終結果、計算機と同じ値を得たい感じです。根本が浅い感じで本当にすみません…

Comment: 金額計算と言うことでしたら、10進法で計算するというのが王道でしょう。「銀行の利息計算」のような厳密な規則が後付けで出てきても後付け対応でなんとかなるでしょう。decimal.jsの方が「10進法で計算する」ためのライブラリです。math.jsの方はどちらかと言うと「数値計算」や「科学技術計算」用のライブラリです。多少の誤差は含んでいるのが当たり前の物理のシミュレーションなんかが主な用途です。decimal.jsの具体的な使い方についてはもっと詳しい方にお任せしたいと思います。質問内容を編集して必要な情報を付け足せば、そのうち回答していただけると思います。

Comment: decimal.jsとmath.jsの用途はそのようになっているのですね。計算方法によってどのように計算方法にするか？など今まで考えたことありませんでした。本当にありがとうございます！！decimal.jsに関しては自分でもう少し調べたいと思います！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decimal.jsはいわゆるdecimal型と呼ばれるデータ型を使用するためのライブラリです。
math.jsはdouble型を使用して高速に演算するためのライブラリです。

この違いを理解するにはdouble型を説明したほうが早いかもしれません。
double型は倍精度浮動小数点型とも言います。名前に小数点と入っていますが、きれいな10進数小数を扱うための型ではありません。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%AE%E5%8B%95%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9%E6%95%B0
上記のリンクに記されている通り倍精度浮動小数点数では、一つの数字のために
符号(±)に1ビット、指数(範囲の広さ)に11ビット、仮数(精度)に52ビット、計64ビット(8バイト)使用します。
仮数52ビットが有効桁数、つまり精度のために使用可能なビット数です。(けち表現による隠れビットも本当はありますが、ここでは述べません。)
また全ての数を**2進数**として記録し解釈します。(**10進数を表現するためのデータ型ではない**のです。)
52ビットで表現可能な数の種類は、2^52 = 4×2^50 ≒4×10^15のパターンあり、逆に言うと4×10^15程度のパターンしかないです。**double型の有効精度は10^-15程度**だと覚えておくと役に立つこともあるでしょう。

例えばピザを2等分、4等分、8等分、・・・、2^52等分したとしてもピッタリ10等分にはならないですよね。
2^52等分したピザをかき集めて10等分したピザにかなり近づけることはできますが、ピッタリ10等分にはなりません。それが前回の質問において誤差が発生した理由です。ピザカッターを入れる回数(≒仮数のビット数)をどれだけ増やしてもやはり10等分にはならないのです。

科学計算ではこの誤差を受け入れます。科学計算がデータに求める要件は効率よくデータが格納でき、かつ処理速度が十分速いことです。そのためには2進数でデータを表現するのが効率的なのでdoubleはそのように設計されています。

一方でdecimal型は最初から10進数を前提としてデータ型が構成されています。10等分できるピザカッターがあれば、**完全に**公平にピザを分割できるわけですね。ただし例えば0.000000000000000001を表現するためにはそれだけビット数が必要になります。実装系によりますが、decimalにも精度の限界はあります。(おおよそ20桁～30桁ぐらいが主流のようです)。bigdecimalとか呼ばれる可変長バイトのdecimalを使用すると、無限に近い精度を得ることもできると思いますが、実用的ではありません。精度を求めると計算速度が大きく低下するのです。

Comment: 関連するキーワードとしてmachine epsilonやulpなどがあります。数値計算を行う人には重要なキーワードになるでしょう。https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon　https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place

Comment: 追加の補足としてjavascriptで数値を表現するための型であるnumber型は、回答で述べたdouble型と同じです。次のURLにもそう書いてあります。https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/Number

Comment: より細かな説明ありがとうございます！数値型に関しては本当に恥ずかしながら目を背けて生きていたので、これを機に教えていただいたURLなど参考にして勉強したいと思います！ありがとうございます！！